# Test output data with input data in jest enzyme

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, enzyme

I am trying to test an API call for log in user. Now what I want is to send `email and password` as input and expect object with `{ success: true, message: 'logged in'}`. With my current test, I can test with input `{ success: true, message: 'logged in' }` but not with `email and password`.

Below is my api call in separate file.

```
import axios from 'axios';
export function authService(user, apiEndpoint) {
  return axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/${apiEndpoint}`,
    user,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }  
    }
  )
  .then(response => {
    return response;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return error;
  });
}
```

Here is the mock file for axios.

```
module.exports = {
  post: (apiEndpoint, data) => {
    console.log(data) // returns { email: 'blah@email.com', password: '123123', } which I want.
    return Promise.resolve({
      success: true,
      message: 'logged in',
    });
  }
};
```

Here is the test.

```
it('a post request should be made', () => {
    const loginSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'post');
    authService({ email: 'blah@email.com', password: '123123', }, 'login') // authService expects email and password as input.
        .then(response => response)
        .catch(error => error)
        .finally(() => {
            console.log(loginSpy.mock.results[0].value); // this returns Promise { { success: true, message: 'logged in' } } **this is what I want to test**
            expect(loginSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
            // expect(loginSpy.mock.results[0].value).resolves().toEqual({ // I tried this but it fails
            //  success: true,
            //  message: 'logged in',
            // });
            // expect(loginSpy.mock.calls[0][1]).toEqual({ // This is passed only if I pass { success: true, message: 'logged in' } to authService but authService does not expect this kind of object.
            //  success: true,
            //  message: 'logged in.',
            // });
        })
  });
```

Everything is commented in above test case. Please help me out to test both the input and output of API call. How can I do this?

Comment: You don't _call_ resolves/rejects, and you need to return or await the expectation because it's asynchronous. Read https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#resolves--rejects. But why are you trying to test what the post _returns_ - is that not controlled in the test? You're just testing the test double at that point - do you have a reason to think it won't return what you configured it to? You're also showing a classic problem with mocking: your test double of Axios.post returns something that doesn't look like https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend turning the rejection from Axios into a promise that resolves with the error, either, because then everything downstream has to check "did this resolve with the result or an error?" rather it being a resolution or a rejection.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `jest.spyOn()` to spy and mock `axios.post()` method and its resolved value. You don't need to use the `__mocks__/axios.js` mock file. To avoid confusion, don't use them together.

E.g.

`authService.ts`:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function authService(user, apiEndpoint) {
  return axios
    .post(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/${apiEndpoint}`, user, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error;
    });
}
```

`authService.test.ts`:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { authService } from './authService';

describe('68242850', () => {
  it('should return response', async () => {
    const postSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'post').mockResolvedValueOnce({
      success: true,
      message: 'logged in',
    });

    const actual = await authService({ email: 'blah@email.com', password: '123123' }, 'login');
    expect(actual).toEqual({ success: true, message: 'logged in' });
    expect(postSpy).toBeCalledWith(
      'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login',
      { email: 'blah@email.com', password: '123123' },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    );
    postSpy.mockRestore();
  });

  it('should handle error', () => {
    // you can figure it out based on above exmple
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68242850/authService.test.ts (9.331 s)
  68242850
    ✓ should return response (4 ms)
    ✓ should handle error

----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files       |      80 |      100 |   66.67 |      80 |                   
 authService.ts |      80 |      100 |   66.67 |      80 | 14                
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.49 s
```